# Replace blank spaces with periods within column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where within a column I would like to replace the blank spaces with a period.

**Data**

```
Date      id
 
Q1 2022   a
Q2 2022   b
```

**Desired**

```
Date      id
 
Q1.2022   a
Q2.2022   b
```

**Doing**

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('','.'))
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Try `df['Date'].str.replace(' ', '.', regex=False)` or `df['Date'].str.replace('\s', '.')`

Comment: ok thank you, its only outputting one column : Date -  and not the full dataset

Comment: df['Date'] = <above statement> then display df.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace(' ', '.', regex=False)
```